# What does '%%' mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a problem when I was learning python.

```
print('test%d, %.2f%%' % (1,1.4))
```

however, it has an error.

```
ValueError: incomplete format
```

But if I execute like this:

```
print('test%d, %.2f%%' % (1,1.4))
test1, 1.40%
```

It works and prints the '%'. But I don't know why? Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Those lines appear to be the same.

Comment: It means output a literal `%` sign.

Comment: I'll bet your first line was really, `print('test%d, %.2f%' % (1,1.4))`. A single `%` starts a format specifier and *requires* a following format specifier character. How do you then print `%` as a character? You use `%%`.

Comment: What material are you using to learn python, because that notation is years out of date... it should be `print('test{:d}, {:.2f}%'.format(1,1.4))` or even better `print(f'test{1}, {1.4:.2f}%')`.  It may be worth your while to learn from some more recent materials instead of learning obsolete notation

Comment: In which case do you get the `ValueError`, if when you run it, it prints OK?

Answer (score 6):

Since `%` is used as a special character in (old C-style) format strings, you have to use `%%` to print a literal percent sign.

Comment: Just a little addition: It's the *old* way to format a string. Nowadays one rather uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting), see also [PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: @colidyre Good point. For anyone writing new code, I would definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into c-style string formatting.  %% is a reference to this series of string formatting commands.

The following page:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html 
has a "String formatting mini-language" section that answers your question in meticulous detail.